# how to overclock multiple Nvidia gpus - xorg.conf issue?

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, xorg, overclocking

I have a GTX 1080 and 1660ti on Lubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia-470 driver, trying to overclock both. Currently Coolbits is enabled through /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf, but this only allows for overclocking of one gpu. I've tried overclocking through `nvidia-smi -i -ac`, but it just says "setting application clocks is not supported" for that gpu. I've tried adding a xorg.conf file into /etc/X11/, but that just makes lubuntu boot into a black screen. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `TuxClocker` which supports multiple GPUs. `-ac` is no longer supported by NVIDIA or CLI overclocking in general. It's weird and stupid annoying.
`-pl` for powerlimit still works ok though.
Fan speed setting works via:

```
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a 'GPUFanControlState=1' -a 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=70'
```

with `:0` being **GPU0** and `:1` being **GPU1**